# EF core and generic repo, how to stop load related data

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I moved my old implementation of a EF Core to a better generic one, in my previous implementation:

```
    public static class DbService
{
    public static List<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
    {
        using (var db = new PosDbContext())
        {
            var item = db.Set<T>();
            return item.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

when I called the following method, the related Image data was null

```
var list2 = DbService.GetAll<Warehouse>();
```

to get the Image related data, I had to call

```
 public List<Warehouse> GetWarehouseListWithImage() =>
        base.GetAllWhereIncluding(
            x => x.IsDeleted.Equals(false));
```

in the new implementation:

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly PosDbContext _context;
        private readonly DbSet<T> _entities;

        public Repository(PosDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _entities = context.Set<T>();
        }

   public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return _entities.AsEnumerable();
        }
}

public class BaseService<T> : IBaseService<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;

        public BaseService(IRepository<T> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

public List<T> GetAll() => _repository.GetAll().ToList();
}
```

when I call the following method, I get also the image related data, I'd like to avoid this and keep getting a null object (needed for serialize the object and send to API)

```
var list1 = WarehouseService.GetAll();
```

here there are my models:

```
 public class Warehouse : BaseEntity
    {
        public int WarehouseId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public Image Image { get; set; }
    }

public class Image : BaseEntity
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Warehouse> WarehouselList { get; set; }
}
```

hope everything looks clear, if you need some more clarification, please ask, thanks!

Comment: EF Core does not automatically load the related data except if it's already loaded as mentioned in the Tip under Eager Loading section of the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) documentation topic, which cannot be avoided. Use short lived `DbContext` just for retrieving the data needed or exclude the navigation property from the serialization etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks. yeah I read that part, but I'm not sure why the first time I call getall with the generic repo I already get related data, and why with the previous static implementation I never got related data... maybe because before I always disposed posdbcontext and now not anymore?

Comment: Most likely - that's what I meant by short lived `DbContext`. In your new implementation, it's not quite clear what's the lifetime scope of the passed (injected) `DbContext` and whether it's already been used by `Image` repository to retrieve image data, which would have loaded it in the context.

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you so much, now everything is more clear, as far you know is not possible to force EF core to not load related data (I dind't find anything) ? I solved adding jsoningore attribute to the model property for the moment, looks the cleanest solution that I found. If you think there is a bettere solution I'll apprecciate your idea, also if you add your comments as answer I'll can choose it as correct one!

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :) And no, there is no way to avoid it, so projecting to DTOs or solving it at serialization level as you did is the only (hence right) way to handle it. I don't think I can turn the comments into a good answer (but you can if you wish :), so let move on. Cheers!